# What should I do if I forgot to put a job on my application

Tags: job-offer, background-check, employment-gaps

I just got a new job and I had a gap for one month and I indicated I was unemployed just to complete the form. But I forgot about a 2 week job that quit because it was not my job path or something I wanted to continue with. My question is will that raise a red flag or should I tell them. Is this something to worry about or just let it go and wait if they ask.

Comment: "Indicated I was unemployed" does that mean you didn't list any jobs in that time period (that would be more fine) or that you specifically wrote "xx.xx.xxxx - xx.xx.xxxx unemployed"? The distinction is important

Comment: I don't quiet get what your question is here, can you clarify a bit?

Comment: How long ago was this job?  If it was last week it raises more questions than if it was 10 years ago!

Answer (score 4):

> Is this something to worry about or just let it go and wait if they ask.

No. Do not worry about it especially if it was for such a short term. Let them ask as you have figured out yourself!

Even if they find out, it is unlikely they will be bothered about it!

Comment: Usually, by the end of any form/ agreements, there is a disclaimer: _"The supplied info is true to the best of my knowledge"_. So, if you realize you made a mistake and did not attempt to rectify that...well, does not sound very good. Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's no harm in being truthful. There's nothing you wanted to *hide*, you simply *missed* to supply the info.

Just send an addendum mentioning your honest mistake. I don't see it will make a huge difference, but then again, you'll be fair from your side. If they are not going to be bothered in future, they are not going to be bothered now by this.

Think of the other side: If this comes up in the background verification, you have to anyways disclose the information, so why not do it now itself?